# Searching for a $code in a nested php array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Stack Overflowers,

Having attempted to dive into PHP, I appear to have got stuck; I have a pre-generated array where var_dump($codes) is as follows:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(5) "01332"
    ["description"]=>
    string(19) "Derby Discount Code"
    ["discount_amount"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(5) "01283"
    ["description"]=>
    string(25) "South Derby Discount Code"
    ["discount_amount"]=>
    string(2) "20"
  }
}
```

I have form which _POSTs a variable of $code and would like to search in the array above to see if there is a match for $code in one of the nested arrays above. If so, I would like to be able to get the discount amount and description as individual variables.

So far I have the following:

```
if(in_array($code, $codes)) { 
    //apply discount code using $discount_amount
}
```

where $codes outputs the array posted at the top of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick little function you can use:

```
function get_discount($arr, $code) {
    foreach($arr as $item) {
        if($item["code"] == $code) {
            return $item["discount_amount"];
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Where $arr is your array (that you dumped) and $code is the code you're checking for. Should return the discount, or NULL.

Haven't had a chance to test it (typed it up here), but it *should* work as intended.

Comment: Louis, thanks for the quick response; I have removed the $item[discount_amount] for now as I can't get $the_code (added the_ to distinguish) and & item["code"] to match using code http://pastebin.com/nH2Ry0Kh . If you get time, please could you assist further? Thanks. (PS: the code outputs: 01332nay!01283nay! )

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
foreach ($pregeneratedCodes as $pregeneratedCode) {
    if (in_array($pregeneratedCode['code'], $_POST['codes'])) {
        $discount = floatval($pregeneratedCode['discount_amount']);
        // now you can use $discount
    }
}
```

There's no validation here and it assumes you have an array coming in as `$_POST['codes']`. It also assumes that you want to allow multiple codes to match.

Comment: Colin, thanks for your help, I used a mixture of your solution and the one above.